# rigging - foot IK affects torso/upper body

Tags: rigging, armature

I have modeled a school girl uniform for a game and rigged it.
The arms and spine are  doing fine, but the feet that has an IK applied causes alot of problems.

This is what it looks like when its in rest pose
[image: normal pose]

but this is what happens when i move the foot
[image: moved IK foot]

it affects the upper body/torso even tho it doesnt have any IK connections whatsoever, and the foot weight paint doesnt affect the torso part either.
The weight paint are properly and wisely placed in their specific areas and there are no errors that i have encounter until i have added IK.
Perhaps there's one thing i have missed since im just a beginner at rigging so id really appreciate it if someone could help me with my problem.

Comment: You have to adjust the chain's lenght in the IK constraint tab. In your case it is 2.

Comment: i have already done that but it still moves the torso.

Comment: NVM!
I have fixed it, i just need to manually sellect the lower leg bone and add ik in the bone constraint.